# How do I get my current organization's ID in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Constructs in AWS have `this.account`, which will return the current AWS account ID, but how do I get the current organization ID?

This information is available via the command line `aws organizations describe-organization`, and I can pass it through via environment variable if necessary, but I would prefer to do this with CDK code.

Answer (score 1):

There are custom resources available that perform AWS API calls:

```
const describeOrganizationOutput = new AwsCustomResource(this, 'DescribeOrganizationCustomResource', {
        installLatestAwsSdk: true,
        onUpdate: {
            service: 'organizations',
            action: 'describeOrganization',
            physicalResourceId: PhysicalResourceId.of('Organization')
        },
        policy: AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromStatements([
            new PolicyStatement({
                resources: ['*'],
                actions: ['organizations:DescribeOrganization'],
                effect: Effect.ALLOW,
            })
        ]),
    });
```

And then reference the organization ID like this:

```
describeOrganizationOutput.getResponseField('Organization.Id')
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsSdkCall.html